# Assign value of one field to other field of same object of selected list by clicking a button in list view of object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

How to assign value of one field to another field of a same object by clicking on a button, for selected rows from list view of an object?
Here is my visualforce page and apex class...

<<----- Visualforce Page ----->>

```
<apex:page standardController="Investment__c" extensions="BulkUpdateApex" recordSetVar="Investment">
   <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!InvestmentList}" var="iL">

            <apex:column value="{!iL.Company__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!iL.Ticker__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!iL.Updated_Price__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!iL.Price__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!iL.Pricing_Date__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" id="mubut">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="butsav"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="butcan"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>    
    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And My extension class is:

<<----- Apex Class Extension ----->>

```
public class BulkUpdateApex {
    public List<Investment__c> InvestmentList{get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    private List<Id> InvestmentIds = new List<Id>();


    public BulkUpdateApex(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){

        this.standardController = standardController;

        InvestmentList = new List<Investment__c>();


        for (Investment__c invstmnt : (List<Investment__c>)standardController.getSelected()){
            InvestmentIds.add(invstmnt.Id);
        }

        InvestmentList = [SELECT Id, Investment__c.Company__c, Ticker__c, Price__c, Updated_Price__c, Pricing_Date__c FROM Investment__c WHERE ID IN: InvestmentIds ORDER BY Investment__c.Company__c ASC];

        for (Integer countForInvstmntListIncrement = 0; countForInvstmntListIncrement< InvestmentList.size(); countForInvstmntListIncrement++){
            string CheckId = InvestmentList.get(countForInvstmntListIncrement).Id;

            Integer countForInvstmntIncrement = 0;

            for (Investment__c invstmnt : (List<Investment__c>)standardController.getSelected()){
                if (CheckId.equals(invstmnt.Id)){
             //**************************************************
                    // For getting Price....
                    invstmnt.Price__c = invstmnt.Updated_Price__c;
             //**************************************************   
                    break;
                }else{
                    countForInvstmntIncrement++;
                }  
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I want to assign value of "Updated_Price__c" to the field "Price__c".

But I am getting error that is:

> "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Investment__c.Updated_Price__c ".

Thanks in advance for help.

I have updated my code as :

for (Investment__c invstmnt : InvestmentList){
                if (CheckId.equals(invstmnt.Id)){
                    double price = invstmnt.Updated_Price__c;
                    // For getting Price....
                    invstmnt.Price__c = price;

```
                break;
            }else{
                countForInvstmntIncrement++;
            }  
            update invstmnt;  // This is update Statement to update Investment record. DML statement..
        }
```

But I got error "DML currently not allowed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For Help Vamsi Krishna.

I got answer for this problem.

In Visualforce page, we have to change

<<---VisualForce page--->>

```
<apex:page standardController="Investment__c" extensions="BulkUpdateApex" action="{!UpdateBulk}" recordSetVar="Investment"/>
```

And 
Controller has been changed as:

<<---- Apex Controller---->>

```
public class BulkUpdateApex {
    public List<Investment__c> InvestmentList{get;set;}    
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    private List<Id> InvestmentIds = new List<Id>();

    public BulkUpdateApex(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){
        this.standardController = standardController;
        InvestmentList = new List<Investment__c>();     

    }



    public void UpdateBulk(){

        for (Investment__c invstmnt : (List<Investment__c>)standardController.getSelected()){
            InvestmentIds.add(invstmnt.Id);
        }

        InvestmentList = [SELECT Id, Investment__c.Company__c, Ticker__c, Price__c, Quandle_Price__c, Pricing_Date__c FROM Investment__c WHERE ID IN: InvestmentIds ORDER BY Investment__c.Company__c ASC];

//        for (Integer countForInvstmntListIncrement = 0; countForInvstmntListIncrement< InvestmentList.size(); ){
        Integer countForInvstmntListIncrement = 0;
        while (countForInvstmntListIncrement < InvestmentList.size()){
            string CheckId = InvestmentList.get(countForInvstmntListIncrement).Id;

            Integer countForInvstmntIncrement = 0;

            for (Investment__c invstmnt : InvestmentList){
                if (CheckId.equals(invstmnt.Id)){

                    // For getting Price....6
                    invstmnt.Price__c = invstmnt.Quandle_Price__c;
                    countForInvstmntListIncrement++;
                    update invstmnt;
                    break;
                }else{
                    countForInvstmntIncrement++;
                } 
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

In this solution, I had changed the visualforce page by adding an attribute [action="{!UpdateBulk}"]

and In controller, made a function "UpdateBulk" without any interference of constructor and here I used DML statement "update invstmnt" to update records in investment__c object.. And this is working for me...:)

Hope It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

in your inner for loop you are iterating over the records from `getSelectected()` list instead of using your list object `InvestmentList`

if you change your code from

```
for (Investment__c invstmnt : (List<Investment__c>)standardController.getSelected()){
```

to

```
for (Investment__c invstmnt : InvestmentList){
```

it should get rid of the error..

but you can try further optimise the code and keep it simple..

```
public class BulkUpdateApex {
    public List<Investment__c> InvestmentList{get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;    

    public BulkUpdateApex(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){

        this.standardController = standardController;

        InvestmentList = [SELECT Id, Investment__c.Company__c, Ticker__c, Price__c, Updated_Price__c, Pricing_Date__c FROM Investment__c WHERE ID IN: standardController.getSelected() ORDER BY Investment__c.Company__c ASC];

        for (Investment__c invstmnt : InvestmentList){
            invstmnt.Price__c = invstmnt.Updated_Price__c;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi,

I have tried your answer code but it is not working. It is showing me the value of "Updated_Price__c" field in the field "Price__c". But when I click on save button to save the values in "Price__c" field, it is not saving these values in "Price__c" field.

Comment: the method called from the save action button should update the record with the new values. otherwise it wont get saved.

Comment: But I am using Default- Save action of salesforce

Comment: I have updated my code as : 

for (Investment__c invstmnt : InvestmentList){
             if (CheckId.equals(invstmnt.Id)){
            double price = invstmnt.Updated_Price__c;
              // For getting Price....
                 invstmnt.Price__c = price;
             
              break;
             }else{
              countForInvstmntIncrement++;
             }  
             update invstmnt;  // This is update Statement to update Investment record. DML statement..
         }


But I got error "DML currently not allowed".